# Expo iOS Development Build is failing (Expo SDK 48)

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-dev-client

Whenever I am going to create a iOS development build in **Expo SDK 48** (Managed Workflow) with "**expo-dev-client@2.2.1**" package, the build is failed at "Install Pods" step with the below error messages. I am using latest EAS cli and Expo cli.

Command I am executing: `eas build --profile development --platform ios`

The error description is below:

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `expo-dev-launcher` depended upon by `expo-dev-client`

You have either:

 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.

 * mistyped the name or version.

 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

pod install exited with non-zero code: 1
```

[image]

I am stuck in this phase for the whole day. It's very frustrating. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Please find my package.json below:

```
{
  "name": "learnpickindia",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.6",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.15",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.2.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~10.5.2",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-store-review": "~6.2.1",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.13",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.2",
    "react-native-purchases": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```